# Cygwin 'x86_64-w64-mingw32-as' not recognized

Tags: cygwin, mingw-w64

While trying to compile a program on Cygwin, I received the following error:

```
'x86_64-w64-mingw32-as' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I believe 'x86_64-w64-mingw32-as' is a cross assembler for MinGW64. I have tried finding the package that contains this, but none of the packages on the Cygwin installer appear to have this assembler.

Do I need to install one of the packages, or do I need to do something else?

Answer (score 2):

You can answer yourself using
http://cygwin.com/packages/

or `cygcheck -p x86_64-w64-mingw32-as`